# Web bluetooth DOMException: GATT Error: Not supported

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to receive data from my ESP32 via the Web Bluetooth API.
The device can connect to the webpage but after starting to listen to notifications I get the following error:

> DOMException: GATT Error: Not supported

There is another thread that has a similar question but there is a properties problem.
My properties seem to be okay

This is my code:

```
let filters = [];
filters.push({name: 'Custom device name'});

let options = {};
options.filters = filters;

try {
  const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options);
  const connectedDevice = await device.gatt.connect();
  console.log('Connected');

  const batteryService = await connectedDevice.getPrimaryService('__SERVICE_GUID__');
  const batteryLevelCharacteristic = await batteryService.getCharacteristic('__CHARACTERISTIC_GUID__');

  var properties = batteryLevelCharacteristic.properties;
  console.log(properties);
  if (batteryLevelCharacteristic.properties.notify) {
    batteryLevelCharacteristic.addEventListener(
      "characteristicvaluechanged",
      async (event) => {
        debugger;
        //console.log(`Received value: ${event.target.value}`);
      }
    );
    await batteryLevelCharacteristic.startNotifications();
  }

}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

First I get the message **Connected**

Then i get the properties:

- authenticatedSignedWrites : false
- broadcast : false
- indicate : true
- notify : true
- read : true
- reliableWrite : false
- writableAuxiliaries : false
- write : true
- writeWithoutResponse : false

So Notify is set to true.

At the end I go into the Catch with the error:
**DOMException: GATT Error: Not supported.**

Please let me know if I missed important information

Answer (score 0):

Add needed services to `filters` or `optionalServices` if a device does not advertise that service to enable access.

```
let options = {
  filters: [
    { services: ['__SERVICE_GUID__'] },
    { name: 'Custom device name' }
  ],
  optionalServices: ['__SERVICE_GUID__'],
};
```